# How to serialize a through relationship in django

Tags: jquery, sql, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have my models here like this

```
class individual(models.Model):
    individualName = models.CharField(*args)

class family(models.Model):
    familyName = models.CharField(*args)
    individuals = models.ManyToManyField(individual, through='individualthroughfamily')

class individualthroughfamily(OrderedModel):
    family = models.ForeignKey(family)
    individual = models.Foreignkey(individual)
    order_with_respect_to = 'family'

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['family', 'order']
```

Here "OrderedModel" is an open-source app available for Django.

So, now I want to serialize the family model such that I can get nested individuals according to the order defined in the third class. But, I can't find my way, and it is getting too confusing. Happy to answer any queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `SerializerMethodField`, and order the `individuals` queryset using the through relation:

```py
class FamilySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = Family
        fields = [
            'family_name',
            'individuals'
        ]
    
    individuals = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_individuals(self, obj):
        individuals = obj.individuals.order_by('individualthroughfamily__order')
        return IndividualSerializer(individuals, many=True).data
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Got an error, it says that the model doesn't have an attribute, 'order_by'.

Comment: @Chinmay could you try calling `all()` first? `obj.individuals.all().order_by('individualthroughfamily__order')` I didn't need it on my local example, but to make suere.